# Complex numbers implementation in Rust

Tags: object-oriented, rust

I am learning object oriented programming in Rust. I created my own struct for complex numbers. Could you please review and answer my questions:

1. Is it possible to implement C++-like default constructor? I want to replace `let c0 = my_math::Complex::default();` with `let c0: Complex;`.
2. Why should I implement `PartialEq` instead of `Eq`?
3. Why should I implement `type Output = Complex;`? I already have `-> Complex`.

```
     mod my_math {
        use std::fmt;
        use std::ops;
        use std::cmp::PartialEq;
    
        pub struct Complex {
            // Complex numbers (real, image * i)
            pub real: i32,
            pub imaginary: i32 
        }
    
        impl Complex {
            pub fn new(real: i32, imaginary: i32) -> Complex {
                Complex {real: real, imaginary: imaginary}
            }
        }
    
        impl Default for Complex {
            fn default() -> Self {
                Complex { real: 0, imaginary: 0}
            }
        }
    
        impl fmt::Display for Complex {
            fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
                write!(f, "({}, {}i)", self.real, self.imaginary)
            }
        }
    
        impl ops::Add<Complex> for Complex {
            type Output = Complex;
            fn add(self, rhs: Complex) -> Complex {
                Complex {real: rhs.real + self.real, imaginary: rhs.imaginary + self.imaginary}
            }
        }
    
        impl ops::Sub<Complex> for Complex {
            type Output = Complex;
            fn sub(self, rhs: Complex) -> Complex {
                Complex {real: self.real - rhs.real, imaginary: self.imaginary - rhs.imaginary}
            }
        }
    
        impl ops::Mul<Complex> for Complex {
            type Output = Complex;
            fn mul(self, rhs: Complex) -> Self::Output {
                Complex {
                    real: self.real * rhs.real - self.imaginary * rhs.imaginary, 
                    imaginary: self.real * rhs.imaginary + self.imaginary * rhs.real
                }
            }
        }
    
        impl PartialEq for Complex {
            fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
                self.real == other.real && self.imaginary == other.imaginary
            }
        }
    
        
    }
    
    
    fn main() {
        let c0 = my_math::Complex::default();
        assert!(c0.real == 0);
        assert!(c0.imaginary == 0);
    
        let c1 = my_math::Complex{real: 1, imaginary: 10};
        let c2 = my_math::Complex::new(2, 20);
        
        let c3 = c1 + c2;
        let c3_expected = my_math::Complex::new(3, 30);
        assert!(c3 == c3_expected);
        
        println!("{}", c3);
    }
```

Comment: We can review the code, but the specific questions aren't suitable for Code Review.  We can't advise on changing the functionality of the code, nor explain why you wrote your code the way you did.

Comment: You may want to ask these questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @TobySpeight my aim is to learn the best practices of rust OOP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Derive `PartialEq` (and possibly `Eq` too) and `Default` instead of manually implementing them

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq, Default)]
pub struct Complex {
     // Complex numbers (real, image * i)
     pub real: i32,
     pub imaginary: i32 
}
```

This simplifies the code.

#### Remove `use std::cmp::PartialEq;`

It's redundant - [`PartialEq` is in the prelude](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/prelude/v1/index.html).

#### Always `#[derive(Debug)]` for your types

This lets them be printed in a programmer-convienent format.

#### Implement `Clone` and `Copy` for `Complex`

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub struct Complex {
     // Complex numbers (real, image * i)
     pub real: i32,
     pub imaginary: i32 
}
```

This lets `Complex` be copied when needed, and as a bonus, implementing `Copy` permits some optimizations with standard library types.

#### Use `assert_eq!()` when appropriate

Replace `assert!(x == y)` with `assert_eq!(x, y)`. This prints `x` and `y` in case the assert fails. This requires them to implement `Debug`.

#### Implement `Eq` too

I don't know why you decided you should not implement it; you should implement it wherever you can.

#### Format your code with rustfmt

This makes your code follow the official Rust style.

#### Use [`derive_more`](https://docs.rs/derive_more/)

This is not necessary (I for one would not do that), but if you're fine with introducing a dependency, you can avoid the manual implementation of the ops
and even `new` with `derive_more`:

```rust
#[derive(
    Debug,
    Clone,
    Copy,
    PartialEq,
    Eq,
    Default,
    derive_more::Constructor,
    derive_more::Add,
    derive_more::Sub,
)]
pub struct Complex {
    // Complex numbers (real, image * i)
    pub real: i32,
    pub imaginary: i32,
}
```

#### Change the comment inside `Complex` to be a doc comment

This will document the struct better.

```rust
/// Complex numbers (real, image * i)
pub struct Complex {
    pub real: i32,
    pub imaginary: i32,
}
```

#### Use [struct field init shorthand](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/struct-expr.html#struct-field-init-shorthand)

If you don't use `derive_more` for `new()`, instead of specifying `field: field` just say `field`:

```rust
pub fn new(real: i32, imaginary: i32) -> Complex {
    Complex { real, imaginary }
}
```

#### Don't specify RHS's type

It is defaulted to the same type as the implementing type, so no need to specify it.

```rust
impl ops::Mul for Complex { ... }
```

#### Final code

The code with all changes including `derive_more`:

```rust
mod my_math {
    use std::fmt;

    #[derive(
        Debug,
        Clone,
        Copy,
        PartialEq,
        Eq,
        Default,
        derive_more::Constructor,
        derive_more::Add,
        derive_more::Sub,
    )]
    /// Complex numbers (real, image * i)
    pub struct Complex {
        pub real: i32,
        pub imaginary: i32,
    }

    impl fmt::Display for Complex {
        fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
            write!(f, "({}, {}i)", self.real, self.imaginary)
        }
    }

    impl ops::Mul for Complex {
        type Output = Complex;
        fn mul(self, rhs: Complex) -> Self::Output {
            Complex {
                real: self.real * rhs.real - self.imaginary * rhs.imaginary,
                imaginary: self.real * rhs.imaginary + self.imaginary * rhs.real,
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let c0 = my_math::Complex::default();
    assert_eq!(c0.real, 0);
    assert_eq!(c0.imaginary, 0);

    let c1 = my_math::Complex {
        real: 1,
        imaginary: 10,
    };
    let c2 = my_math::Complex::new(2, 20);

    let c3 = c1 + c2;
    let c3_expected = my_math::Complex::new(3, 30);
    assert_eq!(c3, c3_expected);

    println!("{}", c3);
}
```

The code with all changes not including `derive_more`:

````rust
mod my_math {
    use std::fmt;
    use std::ops;

    #[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq, Default)]
    /// Complex numbers (real, image * i)
    pub struct Complex {
        pub real: i32,
        pub imaginary: i32,
    }

    impl Complex {
        pub fn new(real: i32, imaginary: i32) -> Complex {
            Complex { real, imaginary }
        }
    }

    impl fmt::Display for Complex {
        fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
            write!(f, "({}, {}i)", self.real, self.imaginary)
        }
    }

    impl ops::Add for Complex {
        type Output = Complex;
        fn add(self, rhs: Complex) -> Complex {
            Complex {
                real: rhs.real + self.real,
                imaginary: rhs.imaginary + self.imaginary,
            }
        }
    }

    impl ops::Sub for Complex {
        type Output = Complex;
        fn sub(self, rhs: Complex) -> Complex {
            Complex {
                real: self.real - rhs.real,
                imaginary: self.imaginary - rhs.imaginary,
            }
        }
    }

    impl ops::Mul for Complex {
        type Output = Complex;
        fn mul(self, rhs: Complex) -> Self::Output {
            Complex {
                real: self.real * rhs.real - self.imaginary * rhs.imaginary,
                imaginary: self.real * rhs.imaginary + self.imaginary * rhs.real,
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let c0 = my_math::Complex::default();
    assert_eq!(c0.real, 0);
    assert_eq!(c0.imaginary, 0);

    let c1 = my_math::Complex {
        real: 1,
        imaginary: 10,
    };
    let c2 = my_math::Complex::new(2, 20);

    let c3 = c1 + c2;
    let c3_expected = my_math::Complex::new(3, 30);
    assert_eq!(c3, c3_expected);

    println!("{}", c3);
}
```
````

Comment: Why do you have only impl ops::Mul  in derive_more iplementation?

Comment: @mascai You mean why I don't have it? Because it's not multiplying the fields in order.

Comment: I'd also get rid of the redundant `Complex` type statements in the implementations and replace them with `Self` and `Self::Output` respectively.

Comment: @RichardNeumann This is subjective; some people prefer specifying the type name.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Chayim's great answer, you can also make your `struct Complex` more generic and let the user decide what numeric types they want to use.

For this generic code, [`num_traits`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/latest/num_traits/) comes in very handy.

````
use num_traits::Num;

#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, Default, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct Complex<R, I>
where
    R: Num,
    I: Num,
{
    real: R,
    imaginary: I,
}

///
/// ```
/// use complex::Complex;
///
/// let num = Complex::new(-1, 10u8);
/// assert_eq!(num.real(), -1);
/// assert_eq!(num.imaginary(), 10u8);
///
/// let num = Complex::new(-1, 10u8);
/// assert_eq!(num.real(), -1);
/// assert_eq!(num.imaginary(), 10u8);
/// ```
impl<R, I> Complex<R, I>
where
    R: Clone + Num,
    I: Clone + Num,
{
    pub fn new(real: R, imaginary: I) -> Self {
        Self { real, imaginary }
    }

    pub fn real(&self) -> R {
        self.real.clone()
    }

    pub fn imaginary(&self) -> I {
        self.imaginary.clone()
    }

    /// # Examples
    /// ```
    /// use complex::Complex;
    ///
    /// let num = Complex::new(1, 10);
    /// assert!(num.as_real().is_err());
    ///
    /// let num = Complex::new(-12, 0);
    /// assert_eq!(num.as_real(), Ok(-12));
    /// ```
    pub fn as_real(&self) -> Result<R, &'static str> {
        if self.imaginary == I::zero() {
            Ok(self.real.clone())
        } else {
            Err("imaginary component is non-zero")
        }
    }
}
````

You may also want to consider to implement the common binary operations with real numbers:

````
/// # Examples
/// ```
/// use complex::Complex;
///
/// let lhs = Complex::new(1, 10);
/// let rhs = 5;
/// let sum = Complex::new(6, 10);
///
/// assert_eq!(lhs + rhs, sum);
/// ```
impl<R, I> Add<R> for Complex<R, I>
where
    R: Num,
    I: Num,
{
    type Output = Complex<R, I>;

    fn add(self, rhs: R) -> Self::Output {
        Self::Output {
            real: rhs + self.real,
            imaginary: self.imaginary,
        }
    }
}

/// # Examples
/// ```
/// use complex::Complex;
///
/// let lhs = Complex::new(4, -3);
/// let rhs = -3;
/// let product = Complex::new(-12, 9);
///
/// assert_eq!(lhs * rhs, product);
/// ```
impl<R, I, N> Mul<N> for Complex<R, I>
where
    R: From<N> + Num,
    I: From<N> + Num,
    N: Copy + Num,
{
    type Output = Complex<R, I>;

    fn mul(self, rhs: N) -> Self::Output {
        Self::Output {
            real: self.real * rhs.into(),
            imaginary: self.imaginary * rhs.into(),
        }
    }
}

/// # Examples
/// ```
/// use complex::Complex;
///
/// let lhs = Complex::new(4, -3);
/// let rhs = 12;
/// let difference = Complex::new(-8, -3);
///
/// assert_eq!(lhs - rhs, difference);
/// ```
impl<R, I> Sub<R> for Complex<R, I>
where
    R: Num,
    I: From<R> + Num,
{
    type Output = Complex<R, I>;

    fn sub(self, rhs: R) -> Self::Output {
        Self::Output {
            real: self.real - rhs,
            imaginary: self.imaginary,
        }
    }
}
````

Note that I use doctests to directly test the respective implementations for their correctness, instead of using a main function.

It also might be handy to be able to convert real numbers to complex numbers:

````
/// # Examples
/// ```
/// use complex::Complex;
///
/// let lhs: Complex<u32, i64> = 12.into();
/// let rhs = Complex::new(12u32, 0i64);
///
/// assert_eq!(lhs, rhs);
/// ```
impl<R, I> From<R> for Complex<R, I>
where
    R: Clone + Num,
    I: Clone + Num,
{
    fn from(real: R) -> Self {
        Self::new(real, I::zero())
    }
}
````